# How to access the function from other function

Tags: python

json below

`data = [{"id":1,"name":"a"},{"id":2,"name":"b"},{"id":3,"name":"c"}]`

- I have large json and i am extracting `id` from that through one function
- My second function will extract the count of elements

```
    #extract the id from the json
    total  = []
    def id_extract(data):
        for i in data:
            j = {"id" : i["id"]}
            total.append(j)
        return total 
    
    #extract length from the json
    def length_(data):
        return(len(data))
```

My current output is  `[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]`

Expected out is  `[{'count':3}{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]`

NB: This question is mainly to attention of passing of one function to other function

Comment: With how your code is set up you don't need to pass anything, just change `length_` to `total.insert(0, {'count': len(data)})`... Anyway it is not clear what is your output, these are just function definitions. Can you provide a [mre] with the exact input and expected output?

Comment: @Tomerikoo edited the function

Comment: That was not the main problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? no need to return a list as it is mutable, there are better ways of writing this off course but as far as calling a function from another, you can usually just call it.

```
def id_extract(data):
    cur_count = {"count": length(data)}
    total.append(cur_count)

    for i in data:
        j = {"id": i["id"]}
        total.append(j)

# extract length from the json
def length(data):
    return(len(data))
```

Comment: I got none `data = [{"id":1,"name":"a"},{"id":2,"name":"b"},{"id":3,"name":"c"}]
def id_extract(data):
    total = []
    cur_count = {"count": length(data)}
    total.append(cur_count)

    for i in data:
        j = {"id": i["id"]}
        total.append(j)

# extract length from the json
def length(data):
    return(len(data))
print (id_extract(data))`

Answer (score 2):

You want something like that ?

```
#extract the id from the json
def id_extract(data):
    return [{"id" : e["id"]} for e in data]

#extract length from the json
def add_length(data):
    data.insert(0, {"count" : len(data)}) # insert the element at the first position

data = [{"id":1,"name":"a"},{"id":2,"name":"b"},{"id":3,"name":"c"}]

d = id_extract(data)
print(d) # OUTPUT : [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
add_length(d)
print(d) # OUTPUT : [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'count': 3}]
```

A list is [mutable](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747) so I don't need to return the list in the `add_length` function.

Comment: can we add  {'count': 3} at the beginning

Comment: yes like this `data.insert(0, {"count" : len(data)})`

Comment: Hah you beat me to it, This is definitely more pythonic than my answer :)

Comment: if i want to return and then i need to pass to another function, then how to do?